# Why the java script loop is not running after if statement in this code?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I want to print the year between 2014 and 2050 when the date is 1, day is 0 (Sunday) and month is 0 (Jan) this is the code, where I'm doing wrong?

```
//Write a JavaScript program to find 1st January is being a Sunday between 2014 and 2050.

for (var year = 2014; year <=2050; year++){
    var today = new Date();
    var month =  today.getMonth();
    var date  =  today.getDate();
    var year1  =  today.getFullYear();
    var day   =  today.getDay();
    // console.log(year);
if (date === 1 && day === 0 && month == 0){
    console.log(year);
}    else{
    alert("error");
}; break

};
```

Comment: You need to set the Date when you create it. new Date() will return current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had reviewed your code and here is the analysis of your code

1. The following line of code
   `}; break`
   Exits your loop after the first iteration, so that is not required.
2. Your line of code
   `new Date();` 
   Always returns the today's date.
3. So instead you need to call it like:
   `new Date(year, 0, 1);`
   So , this gives you the 1st January for each year in the loop .

Hence, you just need to validate if that is a Sunday or not with the following If condition :

```
let date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
// checks if 1st Jan for the specific year is === 0 (sunday)
if ( date.getDay() === 0 ) {
```

Here is the final working code:

```js
//Write a JavaScript program to find 1st January is being a Sunday between 2014 and 2050.
var year;
for (year = 2014; year <=2050; year++){
  let date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
// checks if 1st Jan for the specific year is === 0 (sunday)
if ( date.getDay() === 0 ) {
    console.log(year);
} else{
    // console.log("error");
};

};
```

References : 
Syntax : `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just wanted to clarify that will same result can be obtained using new **Date();** any other way?

Comment: Any specific reason, My answer did not meet your acceptance criteria ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `new Date(year, 0, 1)` after every iteration and then, check if it is **Sunday** or not.

`new Date(year, 0, 1)`

`year` will feed the variable

`0` represents the index of January

`1` represents 1<sup>st</sup> of January

```js
var date;
for (var year = 2014; year <= 2050; year++) {
  date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  if (date.getDay() === 0) console.log(year);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

```
for (var year = 2014; year <= 2050; year++) {
  var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  if (d.getDay() === 0){
    console.log(year);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where is the code wrong. I need clarification as there is an downvote for this answer. Let me know the correct answer.

Comment: You got the downvote for your explanatory text *This might help.* - not for your code.